# Green's function of 2D Poisson equation in the lower half-plane with Neumann boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

The solution of the 2D Poisson equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2}=\delta(x-x_s)\delta(y-y_s) \tag{*}
$$
subjected to the boundary condition $V(\infty)=0$ is:
$$
G(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|r-r_s|
$$
**Question:** What is the solution of (*) subjected to the following boundary conditions?
$$
V(x\to\pm\infty)=0\\
V(y\to-\infty)=0\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\left|_{y=0}\right.=0
$$

Comment: First of all, please note that $G(x,y)$ is the fundamental solution for the poisson equation in the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, and it can be considered a Green's function only if we consider the "point at infinity" of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a boundary where $G(x,y)$ is required to vanish. Then, having a look to your question, it seems that you need to know the Green's functions for the upper half plane: is it so?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri You are right. I was providing background information by mentioning $G(x,y)$. My main question is the solution of the Poisson's equation in the **lower** half plane, whose derivative vanishes at the plane boundary. In other word, I am looking for the solution in the domain:
$$
x \in (-\infty,\infty), y \in [0,-\infty)
$$

Comment: Look up the method of images. The solution should be $$ V(x,y) = G(x-x_s,y-y_s) + G(x-x_s,y+y_s) $$ where $G$ is the Green's function in free space. This is valid for both the upper and lower half-plane, due to symmetry

Comment: @Dylan Just want to confirm the solution. Do you mean that $V=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\ln\sqrt{(x-2x_s)^2+(y-2y_s)^2}+\ln\sqrt{(x-2x_s)^2+y^2})$? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started working to this answer after seeing the comment of Dylan and the following comment of A Slow Learner, therefeore I was a little misplaced by the answer by Dylan himself (which however focuses more on the image method for constructing Green's functions): however I think it could be useful to see how the answer is obtained, and so I've decided to provide a(n almost) complete development below.

The Green's function $\mathscr{G}_N(x-x_s,y-y_s)$ for Neumann's problem for the Poisson equation (*) in the **lower half plane** is the solution of the following Dirichlet boundary value problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta \mathscr{G}_N(x-x_s,y-y_s)=\delta(x-x_s,y-y_s),\quad (x,y),(x_s,y_s)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^-\\
\frac{\partial\mathscr{G}_N}{\partial y}(x-x_s,-y_s)=0
\end{cases}.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Note that $\frac{\partial\mathscr{G}_N}{\partial\mathbf{n}}=\frac{\partial\mathscr{G}}{\partial y}$ on the boundary $\{y=0\}$ of the lower half plane.

According to Vladimirov ((1983) §29.1, p. 368)), the general solution of problem \eqref{1} has the following form
$$
\mathscr{G}_N(x-x_s,y-y_s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|(x,y)-(x_s,y_s)|+g(x-x_s,y-y_s)
$$
where the first term on the right side is the *fundamental solution* of the laplacian while the second one is a function harmonic in the whole $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^-$. In the problem posed by the OP,
$$
\mathscr{G}_N(x-x_s,y-y_s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\big(\ln|(x,y)-(x_s,y_s)|+\ln|(x,y)-(x_s,-y_s)|\big).\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Since $\frac{\partial\mathscr{G}_N}{\partial\mathbf{n}}=\frac{\partial\mathscr{G}_N}{\partial y}$ for problem \eqref{1}, by nothing that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|(x,y)-(x_s,y_s)|& =\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\sqrt{(x-x_s)^2+(y-y_s)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y-y_s}{(x-x_s)^2+(y-y_s)^2},
\end{split}
$$
it is easy to verify that the function \eqref{2} solves problem \eqref{1} and , by [Green's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_second_identity) it solves the general Neumann problem for the 2D Poisson's equation on the half plane.

[1] Vladimirov, V. S.  (1983)[1970], *Equations of mathematical physics*, Moscow: Mir Publishers, 2nd ed., pp. 464, MR0764399, Zbl 0207.09101 
(the Zbmath review refers to the first English edition).

Comment: +1 Nice work. Just to clarify, my answer was meant as more of a comment that's too long to be posted as a comment, rather than a full answer. Since the method is already well-known, I just provided the solution and some links.

Comment: @Dylan. Thank you very much: I hesitated a bit in posting it because I do not want to predate your work.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's still confusion, I'll just write down the solution here

$$ V = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\ln\sqrt{(x-x_s)^2+(y-y_s)^2} + \ln\sqrt{(x-x_s)^2+(y+y_s)^2}\right) $$

The first term is the Green's function in free space. The second term is the same Green's function but its point source is $(x_s,-y_s)$

[This page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/greensfn.pdf) gives a more thorough explanation of the method of images (and also how to apply the Green's function). The half-plane example shown there is for a Dirichlet boundary, but you can easily infer a Neumann boundary by flipping the sign.

Key points:

- The reflected Green's function $G^*=G(x-x_s,y+y_s)$ is harmonic in the domain of interest, since its point source is outside the domain.
- The difference of $G-G^*$ is **odd** across the boundary, and therefore is Dirichlet.
- The sum of $G+G^*$ is **even** across the boundary, and therefore is Neumann.