# PDE: BVP of Laplace equation on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,+\infty)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

> Solve the BVP:
>
> $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,~~x\in \mathbb{R},~y>0,~~~u(x,0)=0,~~~u_y(x,0)=a\sin(x/a),~x\in \mathbb{R},$$
>
> where $a$ is a positive constant.

**Attempt**. By separation of variables we get $u=XY$,
where $X''Y+XY''=0$, i.e. $$X''-cX=0, ~Y''+cY=0.$$
The boundary condition $u(x,0)=0$ gives $Y(0)=0$ and the only bounded solutions for $y>0$ are $Y(y)=\sin(ky),$ for $c=k^2>0,~k>0$. Then $X=Ae^{-k|x|}+Be^{k|x|}$ and in order to have bounded solutions for $x$ we get $X=Ae^{-k|x|}$. Thus, our solutions are $u_k=X_kY_k$, for $k>0$.

Since $k>0$, $u_k's$ are uncountable. How can we get a sum of the form
$\sum_kE_ke^{-k|x|}\sin(ky)$ in order to use the boundary condition $u_y(x,0)=a\sin(x/a)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to solve your (Neumann) BVP is to use the [Green function for the half plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856272/greens-function-of-2d-poisson-equation-in-the-lower-half-plane-with-neumann-bou/2857604#2857604). The separation of variables and solution by using the classical 2nd order ODE works well if you have a bounded domain, but if you are dealing with unbounded ones, the periodicity of the eigenfunctions is of no help at all.

Comment: The problem I am working on insists on separating the variables.

Comment: If you allow for unbounded solutions then $u = a^2\sin(x/a)\sinh(y/a)$ is a solution